# select specific string from a column

Tags: t-sql

I have data in a table that looks like this:

```
select email_body from email_table


email_body
----------
Ashely, call me.   thanks  --- Original message ---  From: Ashley  To: Lee Subject: Homework  Sent: 3/6/2017 2:32:54 AM GMT  I have a quick question.
Mike, I have all the data you need.  Jim   --- Original message ---  From: Mike  To: Jim Subject: Not Sure  Sent: 3/18/2017 12:02:51 AM GMT  Are you available to go over this?
William, Are you around.   thanks  --- Original message ---  From: Joe  To: William Subject: Nothing much  Sent: 4/16/2017 4:17:23 PM GMT  I need some sleep.
Joan, call me.   Ralph  --- Original message ---  From: Ralph  To: Joan Subject: I need help  Sent: 3/30/2017 5:12:50 AM GMT  Call Rich.
```

I would like to just return the date and time listed in the email_body:

```
Results:

Original_message
----------------
3/6/2017 2:32:54 AM
3/18/2017 12:02:51 AM
4/16/2017 4:17:23 PM
3/30/2017 5:12:50 AM
```

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code and let us know whats troubling you

Answer (score 3):

Because the date length can vary (for example `1/1/2017` vs `12/12/2017`),
You need to find where it starts (thats easy - 6 chars after the `Sent:`) and where it ends (that would be 2 chars before `M GMT`).
The rest is done with `substring`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(email_body, CHARINDEX('Sent:', email_body) + 6,
 CHARINDEX('M GMT ',email_body) - 2 - CHARINDEX('Sent:', email_body) - 6) as Original_message
FROM email_table
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but relies on all emails being in the same time zone. The OP should know if that is acceptable, but if not then maybe offset from the hour/minute section with something like 
PATINDEX(':[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]',email_body) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could used something like

```
select SUBSTRING (email_body , PATINDEX ( 'Subject' ,email_body )+1, 18) from email_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a Table-Valued-Function which will quickly and safely extract one or even many values based on a pattern, **AND**, you are tired of all the required string manipulations, consider the following:

**Example**

```
Declare @email_table table (id int,email_body varchar(max))
Insert Into @email_table values
(1,'Ashely, call me.   thanks  --- Original message ---  From: Ashley  To: Lee Subject: Homework  Sent: 3/6/2017 2:32:54 AM GMT  I have a quick question.'),
(2,'Mike, I have all the data you need.  Jim   --- Original message ---  From: Mike  To: Jim Subject: Not Sure  Sent: 3/18/2017 12:02:51 AM GMT  Are you available to go over this?'),
(3,'William, Are you around.   thanks  --- Original message ---  From: Joe  To: William Subject: Nothing much  Sent: 4/16/2017 4:17:23 PM GMT  I need some sleep.'),
(4,'Joan, call me.   Ralph  --- Original message ---  From: Ralph  To: Joan Subject: I need help which was  Sent: 3/30/2017 5:12:50 AM GMT  Call Rich.')

Select A.ID
      ,Original_message = B.RetVal
 From  @email_table A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.email_body,' Sent: ',' GMT ') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Original_message
1   3/6/2017 2:32:54 AM
2   3/18/2017 12:02:51 AM
3   4/16/2017 4:17:23 PM
4   3/30/2017 5:12:50 AM
```

**The actual TVF returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetLen  RetVal
1       101     19      3/6/2017 2:32:54 AM
1       115     21      3/18/2017 12:02:51 AM
1       114     20      4/16/2017 4:17:23 PM
1       111     20      3/30/2017 5:12:50 AM
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetLen = charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1)
 From (Select A.N,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L))) From cte4 A ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```